# Android lollipop recieve media button actions from notification?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a notification that uses the media button actions, but how do I send and receive those buttons? Here is what I have so far...

```
if(mediaSession==null) {
            mediaSession = new MediaSession(this, "Boom");
        }
        //Album art
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_AlbumArt1);
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)img.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        PendingIntent mPauseIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                    new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE).setPackage(this.getPackageName()),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification.Builder mBuilder =
            new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_media_play)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentTitle(playingTitle)
                .setContentText(playingArtist)

                .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                        .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2)
                )
                // Add media control buttons that invoke intents in your media service
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_rew, "Previous", null) //#0
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Play/Pause", null) //#1
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_ff, "Next", null) //#2 nextPendingIntent
            ;
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Music.class);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
        // Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT,intent,0);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager NotiMan=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        NotiMan.notify(notification, mBuilder.build());
```

[Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#controllingMedia) suggest a `pendingIntent` where I have set `null` temporarily, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make a `PendingIntent` for this purpose.

**BroadcastReceiver:**

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final CharSequence action = intent.getAction();
        if(action==ACTION_PAUSE) {
            //mTransportControls.pause();
            Log.i("ON RECEIVE", "ACTION_PAUSE");
        }
    }
};
```

And in onCreate:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ACTION_PAUSE);
this.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `PendingIntent` needs to point to either a `BroadcastReceiver` or a service that can act on the specified request. For example with a `BroadcastReceiver` you would have a pending intent that looks like

   ```
   public static final String ACTION_PAUSE = "com.pkg.name.ACTION_PAUSE";

   mPauseIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mService, REQUEST_CODE,
           new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE).setPackage(pkg),
           PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
   ```
2. Next, register the action/pendingIntent

   ```
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_pause, mContext.getString(R.string.label_previous), mPendingIntent);
   ```
3. Finally you handle the action when the pendingIntent is triggered. Here you can choose to use `MediaController.TransportControls` to play/pause the action.

   ```
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           final String action = intent.getAction();
           switch (action) {
             case ACTION_PAUSE:
               mTransportControls.pause();
               break;
           ...
       }
   ```
4. The `MediaSession` should be instantiated and setup to act on the play/pause + other actions.

   ```
   mSession = new MediaSession(this, "Service");
   mSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
            MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
   ```
5. Finally extend the `MediaSession.MediaSessionCallback` and implement `onPlay()/onPause()`.. which inturn would actually work on the playback.

Comment: Excellent. This helped me get what I needed :) Updated my code with most of the added pieces.